# How do you make a text box readonly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, button, textbox, readonly

How can i make a text box `readonly` when a button is clicked using JavaScript?
I have tried different scripts like:

```
document.getElementById("text").readonly="on";
```

but since readonly is a Boolean i don't think it works.

Would i use `document.getElementById` or something else? Can i make all of the text-boxes in a form `readonly` using one script or would i need a separate script for each text-box? 
Could this be done using CSS?
Thank you!

Comment: It might not matter your use, but the client can always copy text by workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("text").readonly='readonly';
```

Javascript doesn't use on/off, it generally uses true/false. Some properties such as "checked" and "disabled" are literal switches, as above.

If you want to work on groups of inputs you generally use class names, apply the same class to those you want to affect.

You can do this in plain JavaScript, but you will have to loop through the values:

```
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName('something');
for(var x=0;x<fields.length;x++) {
     fields[x].setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
}
```

Moving to use jQuery has many benefits since it can all be done in one compact line:

```
$('.something').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Comment: as of jQuery 1.6 you may also use `$('.something').prop('readOnly', true);`

Comment: Thanks Nico. Old habits are hard to break.

Comment: you answer is perfectly fine, just a little attachment

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("text").disabled=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using `text` as the ID, and you have more than one `input` of type 'text', you could use [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/Bvhyq/)

```
var inputBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");
for (i = 0; i < inputBoxes.length; i++)
{
    inputBoxes[i].disabled=true;   
}
```

---

As noted by SimonSimCity

> When you set the property disabled to true, it's not available for
>   interaction anymore! You won't get it when submitting the form and
>   click-events aren't triggered. This is the difference to setting
>   readonly to true. All interesting browsers support both properties.
>   See also: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/…](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled)

In this case, use `inputBoxes[i].readOnly=true`

Comment: When you set the property `disabled` to `true`, it's not available for interaction anymore! You won't get it when submitting the form and click-events aren't triggered. This is the difference to setting `readonly` to `true`. All interesting browsers support both properties. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-disabled

Comment: What CSS would you use to remove the faded look?

Comment: @BunnyMan Use `readOnly` instead of `disabled` and you won't see the *faded* look