# Making a textbox change its attribute to readonly after the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, validation, textbox, readonly

**I wanted to change the attribute of my textbox student_number to a readonly after i clicked the submit button(find)**
Any suggestions to do it. Do I need to insert the script inside the php code right after the isset function(search)?

```
     <style>
        .login{
        width: 500px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        font: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px 50px 25px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: -370px;
    width: 1000px;
}

body {
    background-color:#0CF;

}
</style>



<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
} else {
    include 'dbconnection.php'; 

    $id             = "";
    $first_name     = "";
    $middle_name    = "";
    $last_name      = "";
    $student_number = "";
    $program        = "";
    $year_level     = "";
    $faculty_name   = "";
    $reported_by    = "";
    $violation_1    = "";
    $violation_2    = "";
    $violation_3    = "";

    // Search
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['student_number']);

        $search_Query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE student_number = '$data'";

        $search_Result = mysqli_query($con, $search_Query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($search_Result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_Result)) {
                $id             = $row['id'];
                $first_name     = $row['first_name'];
                $middle_name    = $row['middle_name'];
                $last_name      = $row['last_name'];
                $student_number = $row['student_number'];
                $program        = $row['program'];
                $year_level     = $row['year_level'];
                $faculty_name   = $row['faculty_name'];
                $reported_by    = $row['reported_by'];
                $violation_1    = $row['violation_1'];
                $violation_2    = $row['violation_2'];
                $violation_3    = $row['violation_3'];
            }
        } else {
            echo 'No record found with this Student Number.';
        }
    }

    // Insert
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        $data     = array();
        $data[1]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
        $data[2]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
        $data[3]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['middle_name']);
        $data[4]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
        $data[5]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['student_number']);
        $data[6]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['program']);
        $data[7]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year_level']);
        $data[8]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['faculty_name']);
        $data[9]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reported_by']);
        $data[10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_1']);
        $data[11] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_2']);
        $data[12] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_3']);

        $query         = "SELECT student_number FROM register WHERE student_number = '$data[5]'";
        $search_Result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($search_Result) > 0) {
            echo 'student number taken';
        } else {
            $insert_Query = "INSERT INTO `register` (
                    `first_name`, 
                    `middle_name`, 
                    `last_name`, 
                    `student_number`, 
                    `program`, 
                    `year_level`, 
                    `faculty_name`, 
                    `reported_by`, 
                    `violation_1`, 
                    `violation_2`, 
                    `violation_3`
                ) VALUES (
                    '$data[2]', 
                    '$data[3]',
                    '$data[4]',
                    '$data[5]',
                    '$data[6]',
                    '$data[7]',
                    '$data[8]',
                    '$data[9]',
                    '$data[10]',
                    '$data[11]',
                    '$data[12]'
            )";

            if (mysqli_query($con, $insert_Query)) {
                echo 'Record was added successfully.';
            } else {
                echo 'Adding of record failed.';
            }
        }
    }

    // Edit
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $data     = array();
        $data[1]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
        $data[2]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
        $data[3]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['middle_name']);
        $data[4]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
        $data[5]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['student_number']);
        $data[6]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['program']);
        $data[7]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['year_level']);
        $data[8]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['faculty_name']);
        $data[9]  = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['reported_by']);
        $data[10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_1']);
        $data[11] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_2']);
        $data[12] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['violation_3']);

        $update_Query = "UPDATE `register` SET 
            `first_name`='$data[2]', 
            `middle_name`='$data[3]', 
            `last_name`='$data[4]', 
            `student_number`='$data[5]', 
            `program`='$data[6]', 
            `year_level`='$data[7]', 
            `faculty_name`='$data[8]', 
            `reported_by`='$data[9]', 
            `violation_1`='$data[10]', 
            `violation_2`='$data[11]', 
            `violation_3`='$data[12]' 
            WHERE `id` = '$data[1]'";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $update_Query)) {
            echo 'Record was updated successfully.';
        } else {
            echo 'Updating of record failed.';
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST["homeBtn"])){
        header("Location:admin.php");

    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE Html>
    <html>
        <head>

            <title>Cant decide a title</title>
        </head>
        <h3>WELCOME</h3><h3><?=$_SESSION['sess_user'];?>!</h3><a href="logout.php">logout</a>

        <body>

        <div id="form">
        <div class="login">
        <H1>SECOND VIOLATION</H1>
            <form action="violation_2.php" method="post">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><br><br>
                <label>*Student Number:</label><br><input type="text" id="student_number" name="student_number" placeholder="Student Number" value="<?php echo $student_number; ?>"><br><br><br><br><br><br>

               <label>First Name:</label><br> <input readonly type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>"><br><br>
               <label>Middle Name:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="middle_name" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<?php echo $middle_name; ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Last Name:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>"><br><br>

                 <label>Program:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="program" name="program" placeholder="Program" value="<?php echo $program; ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Year Level:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="year_level" name="year_level" placeholder="Year Level" value="<?php echo $year_level; ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Faculty Name:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="faculty_name" name="faculty_name" placeholder="Faculty Name" value="<?php echo $faculty_name; ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Reported By:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="reported_by" name="reported_by" placeholder="Reported By" value="<?php echo $reported_by; ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>First Violation:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="violation_1" name="violation_1" placeholder ="First Violation" value="<?php echo $violation_1 ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Second Violation:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="violation_2" name="violation_2" placeholder ="Second Violation" value="<?php echo $violation_2 ?>"><br><br>
                 <label>Third Violation:</label><br><input readonly type="text" id="violation_3" name="violation_3" placeholder ="Third Violation" value="<?php echo $violation_3 ?>"><br><br>



                <p>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Not in uniform or improper wearing of uniform" id="RadioGroup1_0">
                    Not in uniform or improper wearing of uniform</label>
                    <br>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Wearing of earrings" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Wearing of earrings(Male)</label>
                    <br>
                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Loitering during class hours" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Loitering during class hours</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Playing of games inside the computer laboratory room" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Playing of games inside the computer laboratory room</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Un-authorized access to sites like Youtube, Facebook and other social media sites" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Un-authorized access to sites like Youtube, Facebook and other social media sites</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Downloading of files not duly authorized by the faculty concerned" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Downloading of files not duly authorized by the faculty concerned</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Tampering, theft or vandalizing the computer units" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Tampering, theft or vandalizing the computer units</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Conduct unbecoming of a CCS student" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Conduct unbecoming of a CCS student</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Not wearing of ID" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Not wearing of ID</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Sporting long hair" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Sporting long hair</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Littering" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Littering</label><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="violation_2" value="Un-authorized stay inside a lecture or laboratory room during vacant periods" id="RadioGroup1_1">
                    Un-authorized stay inside a lecture or laboratory room during vacant periods</label><br>
                </p>


                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Add Violation ">
                      <script>
function changeText(){
   var text_box = document.getElementById('student_number');


        text_box.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');   

}
</script>
              <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find" onClick="changeText();">

                    <input type="submit" name="homeBtn" value="Home">


            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make a text box readonly using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414984/how-do-you-make-a-text-box-readonly-using-javascript)

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're having?  You're setting it to readonly, but then immediately submitting the form.  So you're not really going to notice the fact that the attribute has been set.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The reason why write it this way is because i needed to use the student number to output all the values inside to it and to make any updates. I needed to change the textbox student_number attribute to readonly so that there will be no changes or updates to the student_number if i needed to update the student violation

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("student_number").disabled = true;
```